# munmap_chunk() invalid pointer after successful merge sort

Tags: c++, pointers, mergesort, free

I've run into a problem with my recursive merge sort implementation. The vector I'm feeding to the function gets sorted just fine but then the program terminates with an `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// function prototypes
void insertionSort(vector<int> &target, int first, int last);
void mergeSort(vector<int> &target);
void merge(vector<int> &target, vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right); int &i, int &j);
int medianThree(vector<int> &avector, int left, int right);
int ninther(vector<int> &avector, int left, int right);
void printVector(vector<int> &avector);
void generateRandom(vector<int> &avector, int count, char t);
void reverseVector(vector<int> &avector);

int main() {
    // initialize random seed from system clock
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> myVect = { 3, 5, 1, 9, 0, -3, -1, 44, 14, 420, 69, 305, 7 };
    mergeCutoff(myVect, 5);
    printVector(myVect);

    // generates inversely sorted vectors of sizes 10-49 (10 times each) and uses basic quicksort with lazy
    // pivot to sort it. after 10 loops at the same vector size, divide the total comparisons/swaps/memory
    // costs by 10 and record this average to text file
    for (int vectSize = 10; vectSize < 100; vectSize++) {
        resetCounters();
        for (int experiment = 1; experiment <= 4; experiment++) {
            if (experiment == 1) {
                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> badVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(badVect, vectSize, 'I');
                    quickSort(badVect, 0, badVect.size() - 1, 'l');
                }
            } // end experiment 1

            if (experiment == 2) {
                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> badVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(badVect, vectSize, 'I');
                    quickSort(badVect, 0, badVect.size() - 1, 'm');
                }

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> badVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(badVect, vectSize, 'I');
                    quickSort(badVect, 0, badVect.size() - 1, 'n');
                }
            } // end experiment 2

            if (experiment == 3) {
                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'R');
                    quickDual(randVect, 0, randVect.size() - 1);
                } // dual pivot runs

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'R');
                    quickSort(randVect, 0, randVect.size(), 'm');
                }

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'R');
                    quickSort(randVect, 0, randVect.size(), 'n');
                }

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'R');
                    mergeSort(randVect);
                } // merge sort runs
            } // end experiment 3

            if (experiment == 4) {
                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'D');
                    quickDual(randVect, 0, randVect.size() - 1);
                } // dual pivot sort runs

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'D');
                    quickEntropy(randVect, 0, randVect.size() - 1, 'n');
                } // three way partition sort runs

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'D');
                    quickSort(randVect, 0, randVect.size() - 1, 'm');
                } // median of threes normal quicksort runs

                for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
                    vector<int> randVect(vectSize);
                    generateRandom(randVect, vectSize, 'D');
                    quickSort(randVect, 0, randVect.size() - 1, 'n');
                } // ninther pivot normal quicksort runs
            }
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
} // end main method

void insertionSort(vector<int> &target, int first, int last) {
    addMem(8);
    for (unsigned index = first + 1; index <= last; index++) {
        addMem(8);
        int currentValue = target[index];
        int position = index;

        comparisons++;
        while (position > first && target[position - 1] > currentValue) {
            target[position] = target[position - 1];
            position--;
            swaps++;
        }

        target[position] = currentValue;
        swaps++;
        memory -= 8;
    }
    memory -= 8;
    return;
} // end insertion sort method, some quick sort implementations will switch to this when subarrays get small enough

void mergeSort(vector<int> &target) {
    addMem(4);
    int size = target.size();
    if (size > 1) {
        addMem(4);
        int mid = size / 2;

        addMem(4 * size);

        vector<int> leftHalf(target.begin(), target.begin() + mid);
        vector<int> rightHalf(target.begin() + mid, target.end());

        mergeSort(leftHalf);
        mergeSort(rightHalf);

        merge(target, leftHalf, rightHalf);
        memory -= (4 * size);
    }
    memory -= 4;
    return;
} // end merge sort function

void merge(vector<int> &target, vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right) {
    addMem(12);
    unsigned targetIndex = 0;
    unsigned leftIndex = 0;
    unsigned rightIndex = 0;

    while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
        if (left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]) {
            target[targetIndex] = left[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;
        }
        else {
            target[targetIndex] = right[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
        }
        targetIndex++;
    } // loop here until one of the lists is exhausted

    // then loop through the non-exhausted list adding its remaining elements to the target array
    while (leftIndex < left.size()) {
        target[targetIndex] = left[leftIndex];
        leftIndex++;
        targetIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex < right.size()) {
        target[targetIndex] = right[rightIndex];
        rightIndex++;
        targetIndex++;
    }
    memory -= 12;
} // end merge method, interleaves two vectors into single sorted vector (target)

int medianThree(vector<int> &avector, int left, int right) {
    addMem(12);
    int center = (left + right) / 2;
    comparisons += 3;
    if (avector[left] > avector[center]) { swap(avector[left], avector[center]); swaps++; }
    if (avector[left] > avector[right]) { swap(avector[left], avector[right]); swaps++; }
    if (avector[center] > avector[right]) { swap(avector[center], avector[right]); swaps++; }
    swaps++;
    swap(avector[center], avector[right]);

    memory -= 12;
    return avector[right];
} // end helper method to get the median of three of a given (sub)vector, also places first, mid and last items in correct partitions

int ninther(vector<int> &avector, int left, int right) {
    addMem(16);
    unsigned firstThird = left + ((right - left) / 3);
    unsigned secondThird = firstThird + ((right - left) / 3);
    medianThree(avector, left, firstThird);
    medianThree(avector, firstThird + 1, secondThird);
    medianThree(avector, secondThird + 1, right);
    memory -= 16;
    return medianThree(avector, left, right);
} // end helper method to get the ninther value of an array

void printVector(vector<int> &avector) {

    cout << "Vector contains:";
    for (int i = 0; i < avector.size(); i++) {
        cout << " " << avector[i];
        if (i < avector.size() - 1) {
            cout << ",";
        }
    }
    cout << " (" << avector.size() << " items)" << endl;

} // end function to print all of a vector's elements to terminal

void generateRandom(vector<int> &avector, int count, char t) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 500;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int num = (rand() % max) + min;

        // if partial sort is selected and current index isn't divisible by 3
        // adjust min and max values so those items will be sequentially sorted
        if (t == 'I' || (t == 'P' && (i % 3 != 0))) {
            min = num;
            max += 300;
        }
        
        // in any case, add value of num to array at next position
        avector[i] = num;

        // having reached the end of the inverse-sorted list, flip the list
        if (t == 'I' && i == count - 1) { reverseVector(avector); }
        
    }
    if (t == 'D') {
        for (int i = 0; i < (avector.size() / 3); i++) {
            int index = rand() % avector.size();
            int index2 = rand() % avector.size();
            avector[index] = avector[i];
            avector[index2] = avector[i];
        }
    }
    return;
} // modifies vector to populate with [count] random numbers, possibly sorted depending on t value

void reverseVector(vector<int> &avector) {
    int last = avector.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < avector.size() / 2; i++) {
        swap(avector[i], avector[last - i]);
    }
    return;
} // helper method to put ascending-ordered vectors in descending order
```

I used my debugger to see where the issue was occurring and it's happening after the function has finished executing. The new vectors get created just fine, the recursive mergeSort calls go through just fine and the subvectors get sorted appropriately. The merge call at the end works properly and I can see either by printing the vector contents inside the function or by checking my variable tracker in the debugger that the entire list is sorted. And then just before the function returns, execution moves back to the subvectors and throws the munmap error.

I've read on similar posts here that this error has to do with freeing memory pointed to by an invalid pointer. I don't know why my subvectors would be invalid—they don't get destroyed by the merge function, and there are no issues with the subvectors at any recursive level—or what I can do to fix this. Any thoughts?

The function also goes off without an error when called at the top of main.

Apologies for the code dump. The sections I've included earlier were either incomplete or uncompilable. I'm not sure how to whittle down to only the relevant blocks when I don't know where the issue lies. Hopefully this is more useful

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Probably unrelated: `target.begin() + target.size()` -> `target.end()`

Comment: replace use of `vector`s `[]` operator with the `at` method. `at` performs bounds checks and will tell you if the program accesses the vector out of bounds. If the program doesn't throw an out of bounds exceptions, groovy. If it does, the debugger should stop dead and you'll be able to see the circumstances of the boundary breach. Note that `at` is a bit slower because of the check, but if speed's not important, and it isn't during debugging, it's a really easy way to find and eliminate whole families of potential bugs.

Comment: @user4581301 great idea! I'll see what that turns up.

Comment: @user4581301 actually, implementing that change between begin + size and end eliminated the error. I'll try swapping in the at method if things are still wonky under the surface but...yeah, error's gone lol. Thanks!

Comment: Odd. `target.begin() + target.size()` and `target.end()` [should be the same thing](https://ideone.com/btj3CX). That tells me that you've got something else lurking and [pulling a heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), so keep looking.

Comment: Took your code and without any changes couldn't reproduce. Replaced the `[]` with `at` and could not reproduce. Output's sorted and everything looks good. How big is the list you have to sort under normal circumstances? You could be recursing off the end of the stack.

Comment: @user4581301 so it looks like the function works properly when utilized like I showed above. The problem is with my second call later in the program. I'll update the post to reflect this.

Comment: valgrind is the tool you want.

Comment: Your new code isn't a [mcve]; it doesn't compile as written.  The most likely way for someone to be able to find your bug is to run it under debugging tools that they are familiar with; this usually makes it very quick to find dynamic memory bugs.  But none of them are going to want to take the time to figure out what headers to include, how to define the variables you've left undefined, and so forth.

Comment: @NateEldredge updated to include full code

Comment: You need to get rid of (presumably) irrelevant code like counters and debug output.  Of course, if the bug goes away then, you should double-check those very parts (although memory errors can often be affected by other, innocent code; that’s what makes them fun to debug!).

Comment: @DavisHerring Counters are gone.